# Which account does DriveApp access in a hangouts chats Bot app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

We have a hangouts chat bot that collects data from users who chat with it and saves in a csv file on google drive, The problem is that the script tries to find the csv file from the drive account of the user who is chatting with it.
This is how i access the csv file
`DriveApp.getFilesByName(FileNameString);`

Should i specify the account to access?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: How is the web app published?

Answer (score 1):

### If you write the Web App Script from the account that has the CSV file on its Drive and deploy the Web App as 'me' - the Web App will search for files on that drive.

[image]